# neovis.js cannot display caption of nodes

Tags: javascript, neo4j, neovis

I just started to learn how to use neovis recently, but when I wrote an html according to the tutorial, I found it was very different from the effect shown in the tutorial. The node in the tutorial had caption, but mine did not. I wonder what the problem is.[Mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6tb7.png)[Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4haS.jpg)

I want to know why I am using the same code as the tutorial, my nodes has no caption and the tutorial does. Is neovis.js updated? Because this tutorial is 2 years old, so I guess it is because of the update, but I can't find the newest tutorial. Here is the tutorial link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-1A7f8993M

Comment: Pls show us your neovis result. Thx

Answer (score 0):

neovis.js is version 2.0 now and most (all) tutorials are outdated.
I could fix all my problems using the Github [example files](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/tree/master/examples) and the [API reference](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neovis.js/modules.html).